# Change number of products displayed per page in woocommerce shop page

Tags: woocommerce

im trying to display number of products in shop page (woocommerce) as my requirement but following code seems to not working any more with latest version of WooCommerce

```
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', 'new_loop_shop_per_page', 20 );

function new_loop_shop_per_page( $cols ) {

    // $cols contains the current number of products per page based on the value stored on Options -> Reading

    // Return the number of products you wanna show per page.

    $cols = 9;

    return $cols;

}
```

Comment: I have re-tested this code and it's still works on last WooCommerce version… May be you should try to change the hook priority from `20` to `100` (as your theme might use this hook already).

Comment: finally solved it, there was conflict with my code......